# How to avoid extra newline using "pytest_terminal_summary" hook

Tags: python, pytest

In `conftest.py` I implemented this:

```py
def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    terminalreporter.section("My session")
    terminalreporter.write("My message")
```

The output is exactly what I'm looking for:

```
====================================== test session starts ======================================

...                                    

========================================== My session ===========================================
My message
================================ 1 passed, 8 deselected in 2.06s ================================
```

---

However, when the tests fail it look like this:

```
========================================== My session ===========================================
My message==================================== short test summary info ====================================
FAILED tests/test_example.py::test_example - assert 0
================================ 1 failed, 8 deselected in 2.32s ================================
```

The newline is missing.

Instead of `terminalreporter.write()` I also tried `terminalreporter.line()` but in this case, the output when there is no error is incorrect:

```
========================================== My session ===========================================
My message

================================ 1 passed, 8 deselected in 2.07s ================================
```

I also tried with `terminalreporter.write_line()`:

```
========================================== My session ===========================================

My message
================================ 1 passed, 8 deselected in 2.03s ================================
```

None provide the solution I'm looking for with the proper new lines.

Of course I could check the value of `exitstatus` and add extra newline if needed, but does it exist a more elegant way to simply write a line to the terminal without extra one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to call `terminalreporter.ensure_newline()` to insert a linebreak when necessary. However, on test run failure this may have no effect if `ensure_newline()` was just called before (to avoid inserting lots of linebreaks unnecessarily), so you have to set `terminalreporter.currentfspath` to something truthful:

```
def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    terminalreporter.section("My session")
    terminalreporter.write("My message")
    terminalreporter.currentfspath = 1
    terminalreporter.ensure_newline()
```