# Is there a way to include the param value and name in parametrized pytest tests in reports?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a pytest that looks like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "paramOne,paramTwo,paramThree,expected",
    [
        (True, False, False, "output one"),
        (False, True, False, "output two"),
        (False, False, True, "output three"),
    ],
)
def test__myfunc_method_should_do_something(
    paramOne,
    paramTwo,
    paramThree,
    expected,
):
    assert myfunc.method(paramOne,paramTwo,paramThree) == expected
```

These parameterized tests show up in my IDE (vscode) and reports like this:

```
test__myfunc_method_should_do_something
    True-False-False-output one
    False-True-False-output two
    False-False-True-output three
```

I would like it to look more like this though:

```
paramOne=True-paramTwo=False-paramThree=False-output one
paramOne=False-paramTwo=True-paramThree=False-output two
paramOne=False-paramTwo=False-paramThree=True-output three
```

Is there a way to include more metadata for how the parameterized tests are displayed, perhaps with `ids`?

I know I can manually name them like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "paramOne,paramTwo,paramTwo,expected",
    [
        (True, False, False, "output one"),
        (False, True, False, "output two"),
        (False, False, True, "output three"),
    ],
        ids=["one", "two", "three"],
)
```

But is there a way to dynamically have `ids` just display the name and value of each param? Without me having to manually configure it for each one?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a helper function to calculate the ids for you in the format of your choosing. This helper function can be shared throughout your code.

For example:

```py
import pytest

param_names = "paramOne,paramTwo,paramThree,expected"
param_values = [
    (True, False, False, "output one"),
    (False, True, False, "output two"),
    (False, False, True, "output three"),
]


def pretty_ids(param_names, param_values):
    param_names = param_names.split(',')
    ids = []
    for param_value in param_values:
        single_id = []
        for index, value in enumerate(param_value):
            single_id.append(f"{param_names[index]}={value}")
        ids.append("-".join(single_id))
    return ids


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    param_names,
    param_values,
    ids=pretty_ids(param_names, param_values)
)
def test__myfunc_method_should_do_something(
    paramOne,
    paramTwo,
    paramThree,
    expected,
):
    assert myfunc.method(paramOne,paramTwo,paramThree) == expected
```

Comment: It would be a lot of cruft to do all of this for every parameterized test I want to write. param_values and param_names change for each parameterized test.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different parts to this. One, changing the format displayed. And Two, altering the `pytest` summary report. Let's begin with the test modification to show how one can avoid the hard-coding of parameterized variables when printing them:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "paramOne,paramTwo,paramThree,expected",
    [
        (True, False, False, "output one"),
        (False, True, False, "output two"),
        (False, False, True, "output three"),
    ],
)
def test_myfunc(
    paramOne,
    paramTwo,
    paramThree,
    expected,
    request,
):
    # assert myfunc(paramOne,paramTwo,paramThree) == expected
    print("\nOld Name: %s" % request.node.name)

    arg_string = ""
    for item in request.fixturenames:
        if item != "request":
            arg_string += "%s=%s-" % (item, request.getfixturevalue(item))
    if arg_string.endswith("-"):
        arg_string = arg_string[:-1]
    print("New Name: %s" % arg_string)
```

I saved that to a file called `test_stack_overflow_73746345.py` and then ran it with `pytest`:

```bash
pytest test_stack_overflow_73746345.py 
====================== test session starts ======================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0
...
collected 3 items                                                                                  

test_stack_overflow_73746345.py 
Old Name: test_myfunc[True-False-False-output one]
New Name: paramOne=True-paramTwo=False-paramThree=False-expected=output one
.
Old Name: test_myfunc[False-True-False-output two]
New Name: paramOne=False-paramTwo=True-paramThree=False-expected=output two
.
Old Name: test_myfunc[False-False-True-output three]
New Name: paramOne=False-paramTwo=False-paramThree=True-expected=output three
.

====================== 3 passed in 0.03s ======================
```

The output shows that the parameters become part of the default name, accessible via `request.node.name` if you include the `request` fixture in your test definition. The parameter names are accessible via `request.fixturenames`, and you can get the values via `request.getfixturevalue(PARAMETER_NAME)`. That's part One.

Part Two is changing the `pytest` report summary. To do that, create a `conftest.py` file and drop the following code into it as a start:

```py
def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter):
    pass  # Make changes here using the terminalreporter arg
```

By calling methods from `terminalreporter`, you should be able to update your output based on the strings generated in the test, if you saved them somewhere accessible. If this is your first time making changes to the `pytest` terminal summary, there are some existing Stack Overflow solutions that can help you get started with that, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/65944137/7058266, so that you can change your test summary as needed.